# How to handle 10k concurrent WebSocket connections in Node Js?

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

Because of my application requirement I have to handle 10k concurrent WebSocket connections but due to limitations of node js I'm not able to do this. Can anyone suggest me the best way to acheive it in node js. Currently my application is hosted on AWS lambda.

Thanks in advance.

This is how my code looks like:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

// Create a WebSocket server
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

// Handle WebSocket connections
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('New WebSocket connection');

  // Handle received messages
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log('Received message:', message);
    // Handle your logic for incoming messages
  });

  // Handle WebSocket closure
  ws.on('close', () => {
    console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
    // Clean up resources related to this connection
  });

  // Handle errors
  ws.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
  });

  // Send a welcome message to the connected client
  ws.send('Welcome to the WebSocket server!');
});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.